# How to get Date only from the datetime value?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have an netezza SQL database field that looks like the examples below:

```
2019-10-01 18:51:32.847000000
2019-10-01 18:50:21.177000000
2019-10-01 18:50:56.883000000
```

Is there a way to select the first set of date to be date only like below:

```
2019-10-01
2019-10-01
2019-10-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use built-in function `DATE()` in the following:

```
SELECT DATE(column_name) AS DateOnly
FROM tbl
```

Comment: It gives me an error: SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR:  Attribute 'REQUESTDATE' not found.

Code:
SELECT DATE(RequestDate) AS DateOnly
FROM ANALYTICS.TMP."OutageFullView"
.
I'm Sure about the column name

Comment: it works when adding the attribute in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get only date from current_timestamp or smth you've got is to convert it like this :

```
select CONVERT(date,column_name)
from table_name
```

or

```
 select CAST(column_name as date)
 from table_name
```